# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, cursor, procedure

I write my procedure and I have this errors :

```
Declare @code1 varchar(10), @code2 varchar(10), @lettre2 varchar(5), @lettre3 varchar(5), @lettre4 varchar(5);

SET @code2 = NULL;
SET @lettre2 = NULL;
SET @lettre3 = NULL;
SET @lettre4 = NULL;

DECLARE curseur1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT TOP 1 Code 
    FROM Configuration..ngap 
    ORDER BY 'Code';

OPEN curseur1

FETCH NEXT FROM curseur1 INTO @code1;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if @code1 <> @code2
        INSERT INTO Configuration..ngap2 
        VALUES ('@code1', 'select top 1 Description_acte from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'',  'select top 1 Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'', 'select top 1 Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'')

    if @code1 = @code2
        SET @lettre2 = (select lettre2 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code='@code1');

    SET @lettre3 = (select lettre3 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code='@code1');
    SET @lettre4 = (select lettre4 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code='@code1');

    if @lettre2 IS NULL
        UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
        SET lettre2 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' and index_count=2)

    UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
    SET Coef2 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' and index_count=2)

    if @lettre3 IS NULL
        UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
        SET lettre3 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' and index_count=3)

    UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
    SET Coef3 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' and index_count=3)

    if @lettre4 IS NULL
        UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
        SET lettre4 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' and index_count=4)

    UPDATE Configuration..ngap2 
    SET Coef4 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1'and index_count=4)

    @code2=@code1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM curseur1 into @code1;
END  

CLOSE curseur1;  
DEALLOCATE curseur1;  
GO
```

Errors :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near '@code1'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near '@code2'.

---------------------- **EDIT**
Now I have this problem :

```
Declare @code1 varchar(10),@code2 varchar(10), @lettre2 varchar(5), @lettre3 varchar(5), @lettre4 varchar(5);
SET @code2 = 'aaa';
SET @lettre2 = NULL;
SET @lettre3 = NULL;
SET @lettre4 = NULL;

DECLARE curseur1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT top 1 Code from Configuration..ngap order by 'Code';

OPEN curseur1
Fetch next from curseur1 INTO @code1;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

if @code1<>@code2
    begin
    Print @code1;
    print @code2;
    insert into Configuration..ngap2 (Code, Description_acte, Lettre, Coef)
                                    values ('@code1', 
                                            'select top 1 Description_acte from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1 +' order by Code', 
                                            'select top 1 Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1 +' order by Code', 
                                            'select top 1 Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1+ ' order by Code')
    end
if @code1=@code2
    begin
    set @lettre2 = (select lettre2 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code=@code1);
    set @lettre3 = (select lettre3 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code=@code1);
    set @lettre4 = (select lettre4 from Configuration..ngap2 where Code=@code1);
    if @lettre2 is null
        begin
        update Configuration..ngap2 set lettre2 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=2)
        update Configuration..ngap2 set Coef2 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=2)
        end
    if @lettre3 is null
        begin
        update Configuration..ngap2 set lettre3 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=3)
        update Configuration..ngap2 set Coef3 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=3)
        end
    if @lettre4 is null
        begin
        update Configuration..ngap2 set lettre4 = (select Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=4)
        update Configuration..ngap2 set Coef4 = (select Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code=@code1 and index_count=4)
        end
    end
set @code2=@code1;
FETCH NEXT FROM curseur1 into @code1;
END  

CLOSE curseur1;  
DEALLOCATE curseur1;  
GO
```

> A115 aaa Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 19 String or binary data
>   would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Based on your indentation FYI only the 1st line following an `IF` is bound to the statement, to conditionally run multiple statements you need to wrap them in `begin/end`

Comment: I do it but I have always the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem

```
insert into Configuration..ngap2 
values ('@code1', 
        'select top 1 Description_acte from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'',  
        'select top 1 Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'', 
        'select top 1 Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code='@code1' order by 'Code'')
```

You are trying to run the string into a value...

Try:

```
insert into Configuration..ngap2 
values ('@code1', 
        'select top 1 Description_acte from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1 + ' order by Code',  
        'select top 1 Lettre from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1 + ' order by Code', 
        'select top 1 Coef from Configuration..ngap where Code=' + @code1 +' order by Code')
```

And the second issue:

```
@code2=@code1;
```

Try

```
set @code2=@code1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I no longer have any error when executing but no data is inserted in my second table

Comment: @almaje The string values in the code, are they supposed to be queries?

Answer (score 0):

> A115 aaa Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 19 String or binary data
>   would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

The size of some fields (Code, Description_acte, Lettre, Coef) is less than the length of the string. Increase the size of these fields, or truncate the long strings (may be using LEFT)